# SSO with OKTA without creating app on OIN (independent of client id)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

We have a web application. We also have a separate customer who already uses Okta to manage his employee's access to various applications. This client wants to use Okta SSO for login to our app.

We created a trial Okta account and integrated a "login with Okta" button based on documentation here for a Node/Angular App https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/angular/nodejs/generic

This method allows authentication for users who have an account in our Okta. However, this does not seem right as future customers would have users tied to their own accounts.

How do we solve this? Do we need to register with OIN and only then it is possible for other Okta accounts to enable SSO into our app?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable self-registration for your organization and then people can create their own accounts in Okta if they don’t have one.

https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Directory_Self_Service_Registration.htm

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your customer is looking for a B2B authentication solution with your service. 
To accomplish that you will need to allow a SAML inbound federation between his OKTA tenant and yours. by doing that, any user from his OKTA tenant that will log-in to your service will be created instantly at your OKTA tenant and allowed access.
OKTA have made a great tool for that called OKTA org-2-org which includes both authentication and the feature of synching data about the user from his tenant to yours.
https://saml-doc.okta.com/SAML_Docs/Configure-SAML-2.0-for-Org2Org.html